# Error Deploying Cloud Run Jobs: Namespaces instance not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

When I try to deploy Cloud Run Jobs, now that it's in [public preview](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/release-notes#May_11_2022), I keep getting the following error, where `MY_PROJECT` is the name of my GCP project. I'm not sure what a namespace error is, given I'm **not** doing anything special here with self hosted Kubernetes clusters.

```
# Deployment
gcloud --project MY_PROJECT beta run jobs create my-job\
  --region='us-central1'\
  --memory=1024Mi\
  --image=gcr.io/MY-IMAGE


ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.jobs.list) Namespaces instance [MY_PROJECT] not found: Requested entity was not found.
```

`gcloud` version: **387.0.0**

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Run Jobs are **only available in the Paris data center** right now (a little confusing since it used to be more widely availabile). Hopefully this will be available more widely once it moves closer to GA.

> For preview, Cloud Run jobs are available only in the region
> **europe-west9**

Comment: europe-west9 did it for me. This is not mentioned at all in the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/jobs/build-create-python)